# Why does "toalla" sound like "tualla"?

Tags: pronunciación, fonología, vocales, diptongos

I am a native speaker from Mexico and I just noticed that the word "**toalla**" when pronounced sounds as if it has an "**u**" instead of an "**o**" as if you were pronouncing "**tualla**". This also happens with "**Oaxaca**" which sounds like "**Uaxaca**".

- Could it be that when "**o**" and "**a**" are combined the "**o**" sound changes to "**u**"?
- Why is that?

You can see their pronunciation here:

- [toalla](http://www.forvo.com/word/toalla/)
- [Oaxaca](http://www.forvo.com/word/oaxaca)

You will see that some of the examples are pronounced with "**u**" and others with "**o**". At least here in Mexico most of the times in daily conversation sounds like "**u**".

Comment: I have never heard the word "toalla" pronounced as "Tualla" in Spain. And in the link you give I hear clearly "toalla" (not "tualla") in the 6 recordings.

Comment: @Javi In the recordings it is pronounced so slow that you can notice "oa" but when pronounced quickly, as you will do on daily conversation, it sounds like "ua".

Comment: Mmmm, I have always pronounced `toalla` as `toalla`, but yes, it sounds like an `u` sometimes

Comment: @Alfredo O OK, maybe it's something regional or I have never noticed that in Spain.

Comment: Quizás al pronunciarlo rápido la posición de los labio y la lengua al prepararte para la "a" queda más próxima a la "u" que a la "o" y, diría, que este fenómeno tiene nombre en la fonología pero no me acuerdo.

Comment: Isn't the case for Oaxaca quite special? I think the actual pronunciation for that one comes from Nahuatl.

Comment: It's a regional thing. Doesn't happen here in Argentina... at least not in Buenos Aires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a book I have on Spanish phonetics and phonology (*Fonética y fonología españolas* by Armin Schwegler and Juergen Kempff), this is classified as **la conversión de hiatos en diptongos (interior de palabras)**. Some excerpts (note that not all linguistic symbols are exact, emphasis on **toalla** mine):

> Como ya hemos explicado en el capítulo anterior, en el habla normal (rápida), la vocal [-o] final de palabra se realiza como semivocal [u] cuando entra en contacto con otra vocal (por ej., *lo es* = [lues]).
>
> Este mismo cambio también puede aplicarse en el interior de palabra... Pero allí es menos frecuente que entre palabras, aun cuando la articulación sea rápida.
>
> La tendencia a la reducción de dos vocales en contacto a una sola sílaba en el habla rápida es tan fuerte que las combinaciones "[e] + vocal acentuada" y "[o] + vocal acentuada" pueden convertirse en diptongos. En el habla informal de algunos hispanohablantes, el grupo vocálico "ea" es realiza a veces como [ia]... De igual modo, *peor* se articula [pior], y ***toalla* = ['tua-ja]**. Obsérvese, sin embargo, que este tipo de cambio articulatorio se produce sólo cuando la *segunda* vocal del grupo (y no la primera) es tónica.

In other words, this is a linguistic phenomenon that occurs in the informal, rapid speech of some Spanish speakers in cases where the vowels *e* or *o* followed by a stressed vowel can become diphthongs instead of hiatuses. It is more common at the boundary of words (like *lo es*), but can also happen inside a single word (like *toalla*).

Comment: +1 Yeha, sometimes I've seen how parents correct their kids telling them "No se dice pior, se dice peor".